# How to wrap data on a basemap plot?

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

I have an xarray DataArray that goes from 0 to 360 longitude, and -90 to 90 latitude. if I plot it with `m.imshow`, without specifying the latitudes, the data is offset from the map by 180 degrees:

```
m = Basemap()
m.drawcoastlines()
m.imshow(mean['Qle'].T)
```

[image: basemap with offset imshow]

or I can do it with `m.pcolormesh(x=mean.lon, y=mean.lat, data=mean['Qle'].T)`, and I get this:

[image: basemap with non-wrapping pcolormesh]

What is the best way to wrap the data? I still want the default map layout, with Africa in the middle.

Comment: @HanZhengzu: huh? `[::-1]` just flips the axes, so ever thing is upside down and back to front... it doesn't shift anything.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, found it. `pcolormesh` has a `latlon` argument that automatically shifts the data:

```
m.pcolormesh(x=mean.lon, y=mean.lat, data=mean['Qle'].T, latlon=True)
```

[image: pcolormesh with shifted data]

Comment: What's the difference between your `pcolormesh` subroutine in question and your answer. I don't see their disparity, but reproduce unlikely figure.

Comment: @HanZhengzu: Ahh.. pasted the wrong line. fixed now.